# Unable to disable a mailbox on Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I am doing some testing on Exchange data recovery and I've came across one odd behaviour.

I want to test the scenario where a users mailbox is deleted or disabled by mistake and how to recover from those scenarios.

First of all, Exchange 2013, for some reason, deletes the user account when "deleting" the mailbox. When you restore the account, it also restores the mailbox. I'm not really happy about this behaviour but, oh well.

The odd behaviour happens when I "disable" the user: According to all documentation, I am supposed to see the disabled mailbox when I click "Connect a Mailbox" wizard on the ECP -> Recipients -> mailboxes -> "..." but it just is not there.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863434(v=exchg.150).aspx

Also,

Here are the relevant fields of the "get-mailboxstatistics" command for that mailbox. There is no "disconnect date" or "disconnect reason". How can this be so inconsistent? It it's not disconnected, how come I see no "e-mail" field on Active directory or how can I not see the mailbox on ECP?

```
DisconnectDate                             :
DisconnectReason                           :
DisplayName                                : User, Test
ItemCount                                  : 5
LastLoggedOnUserAccount                    :
LastLogoffTime                             :
LastLogonTime                              : 2015-07-14 9:34:39 AM                           
MailboxGuid                                : fd477ddd8c-absd90-46f1-bafc-ea1fsd92f2d5
MailboxType                                : Private
TotalDeletedItemSize                       : 0 B (0 bytes)
TotalItemSize                              : 57.07 KB (58,443 bytes)
Database                                   : Mailbox Database 062sdf2528
ServerName                                 : exchangeserver
DatabaseName                               : Mailbox Database 08224sdf26
IsDatabaseCopyActive                       : True
IsQuarantined                              : False
IsArchiveMailbox                           : False
IsMoveDestination                          : False
```

Thanks,

Comment: First, what build of Exchange 2013:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098(v=exchg.150).aspx

Try `Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox`.  Mailboxes should remain in the Dumpster for 14 days by default (IIRC).

Comment: Edition             : Enterprise
AdminDisplayVersion : Version 15.0 (Build 1076.9)

But that command only works on Exchange Online. Not on-premise version.

Comment: Fantastic, that's CU8, which is Q1 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the problem. Apparently, Exchange is not doing a good job of updating its Mailbox State Database (can't tell the original name).

You can use the following command to give it a push:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860462(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: On-premises only.  Good find!